# How does SharedPreferences handle multiple .apply() calls one after the other?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

For a small requirement, I need to clear the SharedPreferences and immediately after that call, I need to save a int value. However, the saving of the int value is not working consistently.

```
sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("pet-app-sp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPreference.edit();
editor.clear().apply();
editor.putInt(VERSION_NUMBER_PREFERENCE_KEY, versionCode).apply();
```

So, I wanted to understand how apply() calls work asynchronously. Do they batch the calls in a queue?

Thanks.

Comment: Pls find the updated answer

Comment: easiest way (and the one I will prefer in case if I'll need to write a lot of data asynchronously into the SharedPreferences) is to use `.commit()` regardless of that Android Studio will warn you. it writes SharedPreferences synchronously and immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do they batch the calls in a queue?

No, they don't. `SharedPreferences` were developed to perform very basic tasks. 
The `.apply()` should only be the last statement when working with `SharedPreferences`. So you can refactor your code as this

```
sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("pet-app-sp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPreference.edit();
editor.clear(); //removed apply
editor.putInt(VERSION_NUMBER_PREFERENCE_KEY, versionCode).apply();
```

You should also know the difference between `commit()` and `apply()`

`apply()` was added in 2.3, it commits without returning a boolean indicating success or failure.

`commit()` returns true if the save works, false otherwise.

`apply()` was added as the Android dev team noticed that almost no one took notice of the return value, so apply is faster as it is **asynchronous**.

Basically, `commit()` writes the changed `SharedPreference` value out to persistent storage immediately, on the other hand, `apply()` write the changes to the in-memory `SharedPreference` immediately and starts an asynchronous commit to disk. That is why in case of `apply()` you will not get notified of the failure or success of your changes like in `commit()` which returns you the status of your changes. [Source](https://mobikul.com/sharedpreference-editor-commit-vs-apply/)

And about the question in comments:

> why does the code in the question not work. As in, why do two sequential calls to .apply() not work?

This may sound pretty vague, but sometimes when working inside asynchronous, you can't be sure with output if you yourself aren't controlling the threads or their queue because being asynchronous, there is a valid possibility that the order of two statements can change. That's why even Vladyslav Matviienko(in the comment section of the question) suggested you to use `commit()` which is synchronous and automatically calls `clear()` or you can use my answer, i.e. by removing the .apply() call. 
Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply())

You must be thinking why did they move to `.apply()`. Sometimes developers end up inserting tons of data via `commit()` which is synchronous and ends up freezing `UI`/`Main`Thread

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. However, why does .apply() and then another .apply() call not work?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What I meant to say is, why does the code in the question not work. As in, why do two sequential calls to .apply() not work?

Comment: Before answering your question, can you please tell me the output which you have experienced?

Comment: The problem I'm experiencing is that the second putInt() call is sometimes not working successfully after the .clear() call.

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question.